# Compiling pascal applications to .elf on PC

Tags: linux, windows, software-compilation

I am making a pascal app on my pc for use on my Raspberry Pi, I thought that coding the app on my Raspberry Pi would be inefficient.

I have completed the app and now I need to test the app on my Raspberry Pi. How can I compile the project into a .elf file?

I use Lazarus 1.6.4

Thanks,

Sid.

Comment: can lazarus cross-compile to a ARMv6/v7 target? http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Setup_Cross_Compile_For_ARM

Comment: Humm. I typed "raspberry pi pascal" in google and the top entry is all about lazarus and how to get in on the PI 1, 2 and 3.